# Consulta en PHP sin resultados, pero en PHPMyAdmin sí hay resultados

Tags: php, mysql

Uso este código en PHP:

```
$sqlconsulta = sprintf("SELECT alumno.id_alumno, alumno.grupo_alumno FROM alumno
                        WHERE (((alumno.id_alumno)='%s'));" ,
                       mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$id_alumno));

$results = $mysqli->prepare($sqlconsulta);
$results->execute(); 
$row_cnt = $results->num_rows;
//conecta los reultados a variables
$results->bind_result($id_alumno_pr, $grupo_alumno_pr); 
$mensaje  = 'Consulta no válida: ' . mysql_error() ." ". $row_cnt."\n";
$mensaje .= 'Consulta completa: ' . $sqlconsulta." ". $id_alumno_pr;
die($mensaje);
```

pero `$row_cnt` siempre es cero, y ni las variables tienen información. La consulta SQL que sale del PHP la he pegado en PHPMyAdmin y devuelve un resultado como debe ser. Pero  al colocar control de error (`die`) y la sentencia SQL en PHP me devuelve:

> Consulta no válida: 0 
>   Consulta completa: SELECT alumno.id_alumno, alumno.grupo_alumno FROM alumno WHERE (((alumno.id_alumno)='160195'));

¿Qué puede ser? He usado la misma base de datos y sentencias para mostrar otro SQL y devuelve bien los resultados.

Comment: Si es un id de alumno y es numérico, no debería llevar comillas entre el valor. Quita las comillas que rodean al %s y prueba tu codigo

Comment: este es el resultado en Mysql        
 Mostrando filas 0 - 0 (total de 1, La consulta tardó 0.0013 segundos.)
SELECT * FROM alumno WHERE id_alumno ='160195'

Mostrar todo |   Número de filas:  Filtrar filas:
Buscar en esta tabla

+ Opciones
 Textos completos 
id_alumno
nombre_alumno
grupo_alumno
alimentacion1
alimentacion2

160195
ALZATE  PIEDRAHITA JUAN MANUEL
0101
02

Comment: sin comillas devuelve lo mismo: Consulta no válida: 0 Consulta completa: SELECT alumno.id_alumno, alumno.grupo_alumno FROM alumno WHERE (((alumno.id_alumno)=160195)). el campo es varchar, en PhpMysqlAdmin, son comillas devuelve el mismo resultado.

Comment: Otra cosa en cuenta, debes añadir antes `$results->store_result();` y tendrás un valor en tu linea `num_rows`.

Comment: Prueba a eliminar todos los paréntesis alrededor de la condición y lanza la query limpia a ver si funciona como en phpmyadmin

Comment: Acabo de Probar con $results->store_result(); como me indicó D.Bulten y devuelve bien el numero de registros. Muchas gracias D.Bulten

Comment: Una pregunta D. Bulten, bind_result lo uso antes o despues de store_result? por que de ninguna de las 2 formas deja ver los valores.

Comment: El id_alumno es un entero o es un string?

Comment: Hola, es varchar en la bd MySql.

Comment: Has hecho un print de `$consulta` para ver que el formato de la SQL es el correcto ??. No entiendo muy bien la **s** despues de **%** , por tus ejemplos veo que el ID de usuario es numerico aun que lo almacenas como varchar

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no puedes ver los valores. Estás vinculando las variables `$id_alumno_pr`, `$grupo_alumno_pr` con la sentencia SQL pero no estás ejecutando el recupero de los datos.
Debes ejecutar fetch por cada registro de la consulta hasta que no haya más. Hay un ejemplo en [PHP bind-result](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

Veamos como quedaría tu código:

```
$sqlconsulta = sprintf("SELECT alumno.id_alumno, alumno.grupo_alumno FROM alumno
                    WHERE (((alumno.id_alumno)='%s'));" ,
                   mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$id_alumno));
$results = $mysqli->prepare($sqlconsulta);
$results->execute(); 
//conecta los resultados a variables
$results->bind_result($id_alumno_pr, $grupo_alumno_pr); 
/* obtener valores */
while ($results ->fetch()) {
    printf("%s\n", $id_alumno_pr);
}
$row_cnt = $results->num_rows;
$mensaje  = 'Consulta no válida: ' . $mysqli->error ." ". $row_cnt."\n";
$mensaje .= 'Consulta completa: ' . $sqlconsulta;
die($mensaje);
```

Fijate también el uso del método `error` y la ubicación de `num_rows`.